# Maven build failing in Flex PMD Report report generation phase

Tags: java, maven, pmd, build-error

I'm getting the following error while executing the goal com.adobe.ac:flex-pmd-maven-plugin:1.2:report (run-flexpmd-main) in one of the sub modules of our project.

```
Failed to execute goal com.adobe.ac:flex-pmd-maven-plugin:1.2:report (run-flexpmd-main) on project sample-Project: An error has occurred in Flex PMD Report report generation. A system exception has been thrown: 0 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.adobe.ac:flex-pmd-maven-plugin:1.2:report (run-flexpmd-main) on project sample-Project: An error has occurred in Flex PMD Report report generation.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred in Flex PMD Report report generation.
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: A system exception has been thrown
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.maven.AbstractFlexPmdMojo.executeReport(AbstractFlexPmdMojo.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:92)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.adobe.ac.utils.StackTraceUtils.print(StackTraceUtils.java:48)
    at com.adobe.ac.utils.StackTraceUtils.print(StackTraceUtils.java:66)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.FlexPmdViolations.processFile(FlexPmdViolations.java:202)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.FlexPmdViolations.processRule(FlexPmdViolations.java:214)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.FlexPmdViolations.processRule(FlexPmdViolations.java:224)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.FlexPmdViolations.processRules(FlexPmdViolations.java:244)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.FlexPmdViolations.computeViolations(FlexPmdViolations.java:103)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.engines.AbstractFlexPmdEngine.computeViolations(AbstractFlexPmdEngine.java:161)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.engines.AbstractFlexPmdEngine.executeReport(AbstractFlexPmdEngine.java:138)
    at com.adobe.ac.pmd.maven.AbstractFlexPmdMojo.executeReport(AbstractFlexPmdMojo.java:205)
    ... 23 more
```

Below is the goal configuration specified in the pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.adobe.ac</groupId>
                <artifactId>flex-pmd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <ruleSet>
                        ${settings.localRepository}/example_dir/flexpmd-rules/${flexPMD_ruleSetVersion}/flexpmd-rules-${flexPMD_ruleSetVersion}.xml
                    </ruleSet>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-flexpmd-main</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/pmd/main</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-flexpmd-test</id>
                        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/pmd/test</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flexpmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>custom-ruleset</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>example_dir</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flexpmd-rules</artifactId>
                        <version>${flexPMD_ruleSetVersion}</version>
                        <type>xml</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

We are using the same set of rules for all the other sub projects and there report is getting generated successfully. Only in one particular project it is throwing error.And we haven't made any changes in the flexpmd ruleset recently. This issue started when we migrated our dependencies to a new artifactory and was testing build after migration. I also tried setting failonError as false, but still it is throwing this error. Can anyone please help us to debug this error?